# bash script to execute a command on remote servers is printing the output twice

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My input file looks like the below

name of the file:/etc/hosts

```
10.142.75.6 m1 

10.142.75.7 m2 

10.142.75.8 m3
```

The below script looks for the host names in /etc/hosts and should print the output of the command "nproc", but it is printing the output twice, once for the ip and its corresponding host name.

```
for hosts in $(cat /etc/hosts) ;
do
     ssh $hosts "uname -a"
done
```

Comment: Bash replaces `$(cat /etc/hosts)` by `10.142.75.6 m1 10.142.75.7 m2 10.142.75.8 m3`.

Comment: ...but you really shouldn't be using `for x in $(cat ...)` in general. Let's say you have an /etc/hosts line that says `# * ALWAYS NOTIFY someone@example.com BEFORE CHANGING THIS *` -- your current code will replace those `*`s with a list of filenames, and try to ssh to those files. See also [Why you don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: BTW, logging what your script was doing by running it with `bash -x yourscript` might have made the immediate problem clear.

Answer (score 2):

Presently, you're parsing every word in the file as a hostname -- so you connect to each host first by its IP, and then a second time by its name.

---

Better to use [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) best practices for reading through a file:

```
# read first two columns from FD 3 (see last line!) into variables "ip" and "name"
while read -r ip name _ <&3; do

 # Skip blank lines, or ones that start with "#"s
 [[ -z $ip || $ip = "#"* ]] && continue

 # Log the hostname if we read one, or the IP otherwise
 echo "jps for ${name:-$ip}"

 # Regardless, connect using the IP; don't allow ssh to consume stdin
 ssh "$ip" "uname -a" </dev/null

# with input to FD 3 from /etc/hosts
done 3</etc/hosts
```

Here, we're putting the first column into the shell variable `ip`, the second column (if there is one) into `name`, and all subsequent columns into the variable `_`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to read the first column of the file only:

```
for hosts in $(cut -d' ' -f1 < /etc/hosts);
do
    echo "jps for $hosts"
    ssh $hosts "uname -a"
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see a reason for this to be downvoted -- I obviously don't think it's ideal, but the only place where it's outright *wrong* in any respect is the lack of quotes in the `$hosts` expansion.

Comment: It also doesn't skip comments in the hosts file, but that's also fairly minor.

Comment: I don't think one should encourage poor practice just because it might work for this one particular file.